# Why does Manu Smriti state that meat can never be obtained without injury to living creatures?

Tags: scripture, food, manu-smriti

According to this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44832/22493:

> Manu Smriti 5.48. Meat can never be obtained without injury to living creatures, and injury to sentient beings is detrimental to (the attainment of) heavenly bliss; let him therefore shun (the use of) meat.

Why does Manu Smriti state that *"meat can never be obtained without injury to living creatures"*?  What about dying from old age?

Comment: It is mention because of Ahimsa. You should eat food without harming other animals or creatures. And non veg cause pain to living creatures.

Comment: The verse is said in the context of eating meat. Meat can of course be obtained from an animal which has died naturally but such meat is unfit to be consumed by humans. That is the obvious implication of the verse.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44833/22857